# Return keyword if part matches

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

Excel, Excel VBA, Excel 2010, Excel Formula

I have data like this. Please pay attention to `abc` and `xyz`. Rest of the text is just random.

**data**

```
               Column A
1.             abc rew rpoi uis
2.             qwert xyz wed ref teg
3.             oene abc odsmd 
4.             xyz qwpeo kosd 
5.             abc
6.             xyz
```

I also have keywords in another sheet. Again,  please pay attention to `abc` and `xyz`. Rest of the text is just random.

**keyword**

```
               Column A
1.             abc qwe ertqeweq loiu
2.             asd xyz uji
```

I am looking for an excel solution to do this in my data sheet

**data**

```
               Column A                       Column B
1.             abc rew rpoi uis               abc qwe ertqeweq loiu
2.             qwert xyz wed ref teg          asd xyz uji 
3.             oene abc odsmd                 abc qwe ertqeweq loiu
4.             xyz qwpeo kosd                 asd xyz uji
5.             abc                            abc qwe ertqeweq loiu
6.             xyz                            asd xyz uji
```

Essentially, pick the right keyword, based on a substring match. ***I want to match a complete word (separated by two spaces) within the keyword to a complete word (separated by two spaces) in the data sheet.***

I have tried the Lookup formula, but it is giving me errors. In cell B1 of data, I tried

```
=LOOKUP(data!A1,keyword!A1:A2,keyword!A1:A2)
```

This seems to work for some and not work for some cases. (I have 4000 rows in data and 100 rows in keyword). Not sure why.

I will be grateful for how I could modify my formula to do this work. If VBA will do it, then that's okay as well!

Comment: Can you split up your keywords into three columns and return from a  fourth column that concatenates all three individual keywords?

Comment: The keywords are random lengths. Thanks @Jeeped for pointing it out. Will update the question!

Comment: Standard worksheet function do not play well with strings of unknown lengths or indefinite number of 'split' elements. Look to VBA for an answer as the variable length and number of keywords can be handled much easier.

Comment: Sure. Will update the question to include vba tags. Thanks!

Comment: Are the values "xyz, "abc" and so on stored some where? or will you put them in by hand?

Comment: They exist in a separate worksheet. It's a pre-populated list available already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following User Defined Function (aka **UDF**) will split your keyword string apart at the spaces and test each in turn. Put this into a module code sheet in the VBE (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>,<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>).

```
Function InThereSomewhere(rThat As Range, rThis As Range, _
                          Optional bCS As Boolean = False)
    Dim r As Long, k As Long, vKEYs As Variant

    InThereSomewhere = vbNullString  'maybe "No Match"
    For r = 1 To rThis.Rows.Count
        vKEYs = Split(rThis(r).Value2, Chr(32))
        For k = LBound(vKEYs) To UBound(vKEYs)
            If CBool(InStr(1, rThat.Value2, vKEYs(k), _
              IIf(bCS, vbBinaryCompare, vbTextCompare))) Then
                InThereSomewhere = rThis(r).Value2
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next k
    Next r
End Function
```

Use in a worksheet just like any other native worksheet formula.

[image: Word_in_Words]

The optional **bCS** parameter determines if the search is case sensitive or not. It defaults to non-case-sensitive. B6:B8 has this as TRUE.

Comment: Perfect! This is amazing and it works. Thanks a ton!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Put this in you data sheet in B1 and drag down:

```
=IF(FIND("abc",A1),data!$A$1,IF(FIND("xyz",A1),data!$A$2,""))
```

Comment: Hi, I have about a 100 keywords, so not sure if this will work!

Comment: It wont. Let me think about it.